# Flexible XAML-only layout. Is it possible?

Tags: wpf, layout

I want to create resizable window wich will initially autosize to its content. 
If the size of the window reaches some limits autosizing is disabled and growing controls are either clipped or shown with scrollbars.
Autosizing also must be off when user resizes the window.

The real task is to create convinient resizable dialog window with text control.
When it contains not much and not few text lines it is reasonable to initially autosize the dialog. The amount of text increases and dialog becomes larger. Sure it must have some size constraints.

P.S. I think it's quite a frequent task to define the layout where the guiding role of the sizing during measure pass of the layout conditionaly swithces from children to parent and back.

Share you ideas or existing solutions. May be I'm missing something.
Thank you.

**Update 1**

Let me explain the algorithm:

1) Window is shown (let's imagine all data/content is already set).

2) Its size is adjusted as if window's properties were:

MaxHeight = ...

MaxWidth = ...

SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"

3) User tries to resize the window. And he can do it. Inner controls change accordingly their size.

This behavior is equivalent to the properties set:

MaxWidth= "{x:Ststic  Double.PositiveInfinity}"

MaxHeight = "{x:Ststic  Double.PositiveInfinity}"

SizeToContent = "Manual"

ResizeMode = "CanResizeWithGrip"

Comment: It sounds as though you just need to set min/max sizes for your controls, and include scrollable panels where necessary.  What have you tried so far, and which parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, but you forget about user. I want to let him manually resize the window without limits. Setting MaxHeight and MaxWidth kills this feature.

Comment: `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` *of individual controls*, not of the Window.

Comment: In this case controls won't be stretchable. Consider the window with the only TextBox. TextBox gudies window's size first but to some limits. Then it streches when window is resized.
In other words your solution works for initial sizing only. And it's ok if user is not allowed to resize the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with XAML only using animations/triggers but it's a little tricky.
Just hook into TextBlock Loaded event(xaml only) and change SizeToContent=manual && MaxWidth&MaxHeight=PosInfinity inside EventTrigger using animation.

Comment: That's an Idea, thanks. I'll try it and accept this as answer a bit later if everything is ok. The only question is whether it can be somehow adapted to the user resize action. I want to save autosize feature till this moment cause data can dynamically change through the bindings. Nevertheless, many thanks.

Comment: That's pretty specific. As far I know, there is no way.  Mainly because you can't differentiate between USER RESIZE action and WPF RESIZE action. You need to define new event which will be raised when user will start dragging the first time and listen for it in XAML. 

In order to generate that event, you need to hook yourself into WPF WIndow's WndProcedure, I can give you more information if you want.

Comment: Check out this link; http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/09/a-wpf-behavior-for-window-resize-events-in-net-35
If it dies, you can just google it. The Resizing event will be fired each time user resizes the window. You might need to take care of Maximized/Normalized event too if you let user to double click your dialog.

If you want to take it to the next level, you can probably use attached behaviour without using any code behind. But it's not so easy because you need to register your own event and propagate it through visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

Many of WPF's panels automatically resize based on their children. I'd recommend looking through this article to get an idea of what kind of layout panels are available in WPF: [WPF Layouts: A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start)

But to answer your question, place all your controls you want automatically sized in a panel that automatically stretches its children, such as a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`, and set the `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` properties of the panel to prevent it from growing past a certain height/width.

```
<Grid MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="200">
    <!-- Place your content here -->
</Grid>
```

Depending on the default behavior of the parent control containing your panel, you may need to set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to something other than `Stretch` too.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <!-- Place your content here -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If you want a `ScrollBar` instead of clipping the content, add a `ScrollViewer` inside the `Grid`

Comment: Rachel, thank you for the help but setting size limits by the MaxHeight and MaxWidth makes the control not stretchable. The task is to combine these two features. Please, see comments under my question.

Comment: @voroninp Did you try the 2nd part, about depending on the default behavior of the parent control you may need to change the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to something other than `Stretch`? When set to `Stretch`, the children will size according to the panel's size. If not, the panel will size according to the children's size.

Comment: @voroninp I'm sorry, I still don't quite understand what you're asking for. Perhaps you can include your current XAML and what it does, and your desired behavior? It's really easy to make a dynamic layout with WPF, so I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for still.