# Need Window's event raised after all bindings are applied but before it was rendered

Tags: wpf, window

Somewtimes WPF turns into WTF =)

From MSDN:

[FrameworkElement.Loaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx)
Occurs when the element is laid out, **rendered**, and ready for interaction.

[Object lifetime events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx#intro)
The Loaded event is raised **before the final rendering**, but after the layout system has calculated all necessary values for rendering.

I need to adjust window screen loaction in code behind after all bindings are applied. Now this is done in Loaded event handler. I see how window jumps what is not very pleasant to the eye.

**Update1**

```
private void DialogViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MaxHeight = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight * 0.8;
            MaxWidth = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth * 0.8;
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
            MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
            MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;

            WindowHelper.CenterWindowOnScreen(this);
        }
```

this code implements the functionality I wanted to implement in XAML.
[Flexible XAML-only layout. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299273/flexible-xaml-only-layout-is-it-possible)

Comment: The `Window.Loaded` event usually calls `InitalizeComponents()`, which loads the visual elements. So at the time `Window.Loaded` gets run, there are no visual elements. You can use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to run code at a later [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) than `Render`, which means it will run after everything has finished rendering, but I don't think this will stop the window from jumping around

Comment: I need to set location prior to rendering.

Comment: What bindings are the position based on? You may have to do something messy in the code-behind to evaluate the values and position your window before you draw anything.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the opacity of the window set to 0 (transparent) until you have figured out your rendering/binding and then change it to 1?

Comment: Also I should note that it really wouldn't solve the grander issue that you would like to do this all in XAML vs codebehind, I was thinking more on how to avoid the window jumping effect.

Comment: Here I'm interested in avoiding the jumping effect. Tried Opacity. Still jumps... =(

Answer (score 1):

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(OnRendering); 
    }
    void OnRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MaxHeight = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight * 0.8;
        MaxWidth = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth * 0.8;
        SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
        MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
        MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
    }
}
```

CompositionTarget.Rendering Occurs just before the objects in the composition tree are rendered.I hope this will help.

Comment: This works. I'll wait a little and if no better answer appears accept this answer with bounty. Thank you. Still I'm curios why there's no dedicated event for the rendering of a particular element.

Comment: Nope, unfortuantely this doesn't work. Window is stil ljumpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DesiredSize.Height and DesiredSize.Width from UserControl which is hostet in a Window. Height and Width is known before loaded event.